# Three js how to delete a child

Tags: javascript, three.js

I attached a child to three mesh with this function:

```
.add()
```

How can I delete the child from mesh with a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mesh` extends `Object3D` and you can use:

```
.remove()
```

to remove a child.

Documentation at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D